# How to properly implement a count down timer in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer, qtime

In order to shrink the problem I created a minimal verifiable example below.
I am trying to implement a 60 minutes count down using a `QLabel`.

**The problem** I have is that instead of seeing the time going back, I see the the current time going forward. And no countdown goes back.

Below the minimal verifiable example:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void timerUpdate();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *timer;
    QTime time;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ui->countDown->setText(time.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    ui->countDown->setText("60:00");
    //ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerUpdate()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timerUpdate()
{
    time = time.addSecs(-1);
    ui->countDown->setText(time.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"));
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    //ui->countDown->setText("60:00");
    ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerUpdate()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timerUpdate()
{
    time = time.addSecs(-1);
    ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
}
```

I followed exactly the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) but despite that it still does not work. In addition to that I consulted also the [QTime](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtime.html) class to make sure I was respecting the members function to call.
I tried also another thign which is setting the constructor to [setHMS](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtime.html#setHMS) and providing the proper values related to 1 hour, but that also didn't work.

I dug more and came across [this post](https://crazybaga.blogspot.com/2017/08/qtimer-how-to-work-with-timer.html) which uses a very similar approach to what I used, with the difference that the example implements a current timer and not a count down. That is the reason why in the `timerUpdate()` function I am diminishing time `time = time.addSecs(-1);` instead of adding it. But still does not work.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: `time.currentTime()` is your bug. It gets the current time of the day not the time stored in the time object.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and reading the question. I corrected the bug, but I don't see anything. The label seems to disappear. I updated the question with **EDIT 2** to show what I did. Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Ok it is working! I actually had to use `setHMS` to initialize it in the cnstructor.